# (selenium)If I know only the innertext of the element button, how to click?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium. And to python, too
If the button that includes the specific innerText exists, I wanna click it.

But I don't know any id or xpath. How can I find it and click?

That is, I have only the innerText, How can I find it, and click it?

```py
txt = 'button_i_wanna_click'
if txt in driver.page_source:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(# id_of_element_that_includes the txt).click()
    except TIMEOUTexception:
        "how can I do??"
```

Comment: `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'My Button')]")`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xpath` here like -

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'button_i_wanna_click')"])`

Answer (score 0):

[Locate the element using xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath). For example

```
btn_txt = repr('Post Your Answer')
btn_xpath = f"//button[normalize-space(text())=${btn_txt}]"
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(btn_xpath)
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a valid xpath. eg `"//button[normalize-space(text())='something']"` is not valid when I run it

Comment: This works in Google Chrome web browser. What browser are you driving?

Comment: Huh. I'm on Chrome too.

Comment: That's weird. I'm driving `Version 90.0.4430.212 (Offizieller Build) (x86_64)` of Google Chrome if that is of any help.

Comment: I tried.... But it doesn't work... I'm on Chrome, too.